# Base 10 Decimal Expansion

Tags: real-analysis

### Problem:

If $x\in [0,1)$ write $a_1 = [10x], a_2=[100(x - \frac{a_1}{10})], a_3 = [1000(x - \frac{a_1}{10} - \frac{a_2}{100})], . . .$. Prove that $0 \leq a_k \leq 9$ for each $k$ and that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{10^n}$ converges. Prove that $x = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{10^n}.$ Prove that there is no $N$ such that $a_k=9$ for all $k \geq N$.

### Attempted Solution:

Right off the bat, I'm unsure how to handle the first problem. If I choose $x=0.99$ and $a_1$, don't I get $a_1 = 10(0.99) = 9.9 \geq 9$? This contradicts what I am asked to prove, and I am certain it is not meant to. Am I misunderstanding the way the problem is phrased?

Comment: Your $[10x]$ is the floor function and it will be in $\{0,1 \dots, 9\}$ for $x \in [0,1)\, $ e.g. $[9.9] = 9$

Comment: I see. So numbers in the interval $[9,10)$ simply become the integer $9$.

Comment: Yes $[x]$ is the largest integer $\le x$.